# GET Error while call store procedure in python with SQL-server

Tags: python, sql-server, pycharm

```
try:
sql = "SET NOCOUNT ON;"\
            "DECLARE @out int;"\
            "DECLARE @timess time;"\
            "EXEC [dbo].[VSM_isTradingHour] @date = ?,@isTrading = @out OUTPUT,@timestamp = @timess OUTPUT;"\
            "SELECT @out,@timess As the_output;"
cnxn = pypyodbc.connect("Trusted_Connection=yes;"
                      "Driver={SQL Server};"
                      "Server=SS-88-PC;"
                      "Database=VirtualShareMarket;"
                      "UID=sa;PWD=icreate")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
params = ('2018-05-05',)
cursor.execute(sql,params)
rows= cursor.fetchall()
print(rows)
```

except pypyodbc.Error as err:
    print("Error:---- %s",err)

> Error:---- %s ('24000', '[24000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid cursor state')

Comment: I go through so many articles and query which previously posted here but failed all the time! Can any one help me?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. The current versions of pypyodbc and pyodbc both work correctly for me in the scenario you describe.

Comment: The issue is in SP. I solved it , Thanks for reply